# It is possible to set maximum font and minimum font and be responsive while scaling?

Tags: html, css

I have this class

```
.md-subheader-title {
    // 22 pixeles
    font-size: calc(12px + 2vw); 
}
```

on max size its 22 pixels thats fine, but on mobile version its smaller than 14px, would be possible to make it repsonsive between max font size 22px, minium font-size 14px?

Comment: how much is the max size  ?

Comment: [Responsive font-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a media query to force the font size to be a fixed size on viewports less than a specified width.

In your case, you want the font size to be no less than 14px. This would happen when calc(12px + 2vw) is less than 14px, or when 2vw is less than 2px; i.e. on screens narrower than 100px.
(Those are very very narrow screens, mind.)

```css
.md-subheader-title {
    /* 22 pixeles */
    font-size: calc(12px + 2vw); 
}

@media all and (max-width: 100px) {
  .md-subheader-title {
    font-size: 14px; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="md-subheader-title">
This is a variable font, up to a point.
</div>
```